# URL Rewriting with .htaccess and subdomain issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteCond ${rewrite_map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?shop_id=${rewrite_map:$1} [NC,L,QSA]
```

So the URL for that looks like: http://www.domain.com/company-name/

Well I am developing an iPad version so I am redirecting to: http://m.domain.com/ which works fine but when I go to the URL http://m.domain.com/company-name/ I get a Page Not found error. The m subdomain is pulling from my /ipad directory. If I go to http://www.domain.com/ipad/company-name/ THAT works as well. I just need it to work on my mobile subdomain as well.

Does anyone know what I need to add to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: is this the full rewrite section of the .htaccess file? you need to say rewrite engine on or something to that effect to enable mod-rewrite.

Comment: Yeah I have RewriteEngine On - This is just the main part of the Rewrite Rule I didn't include everything.

Comment: The rewrite posted above works fine for the main URL.  the problem is just getting it to work with the mobile subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured it out by adding the following to my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/ipad%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```